# Which command to use to see DNS entry for mydomain.com?

Tags: domain-name-system

I would like to compare two DNS entries.
One from DNS service provider A, and one from DNS service provider B.

**Is there a tool to extract the DNS entry for mydomain.com from a nameserver?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends what your DNS provider allows you to do. You can do a simple lookup for records (A, MX, NS, etc) with "host" or "nslookup":

```
$ host www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain has address 12.34.56.78

$ host -t ns mydomain.com
mydomain.com name server ns1.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com name server ns2.mydomain.com.
```

If you just want to compare single entries, you can use "host" against different nameservers:

```
$ host www.mydomain.com ns1.mydomain.com.
```

and

```
$ host www.mydomain.com ns2.mydomain.com.
```

Or use "dig" that gives you an more info about your domain and in a bind zone file format

```
$ dig www.mydomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> www.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27232
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.mydomain.com.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.mydomain.com.           600     IN      A       12.34.56.78

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:  
mydomain.com.               600     IN      NS      ns1.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.               600     IN      NS      ns2.mydomain.com.
```

Dig takes the nameserver you want to query in the form of "@nameserver":

```
$ dig @ns1.mydomain.com www.mydomain.com
```

If your DNS provider allows zone file transfers (AXFR), you can get the whole zone file with:

```
$ dig @ns1.mydomain.com AXFR
```

This will return the complete zone file in a BIND compatible format.

Comment: `host` is considered obsolete by its authors.  `dig` is preferred.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. I love host though..